# Dynamic Hostname resolving for DNS based on availability

Tags: dns, dyndns

I have two servers that provide a service to clients.

The client devices access the server through a DNS name.  example.com
Now we generally use server1 (primary) but if server one becomes inaccessible, I want the DNS to change its resolving name to server 2 (secondary server)

How can I go about doing this, Is there a service that dyndns provides?

The only way I know to do it is to log into the DNS server and manually change the addresses that the dns resolves 2.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking to create an automated failover in the event of an outage. While this is a service that Dyn provides as an added service in the DynECT Managed DNS service (hit up sales@dyn.com for more info on that), you can also use the Dyn Updater API to push an IP update up to your Standard DNS account as well. It would be a matter of using a 3rd party monitoring solution to trigger the update in your code using their API, then using the Dyn Updater API to switch the IP.

http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/

Whether you want to spend the money on upgrading to DynECT Managed DNS or keep using your Standard DNS account, we can help you either way.

Good luck, and if you have any other questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

CL